Which Material Design version is my Angular project using?
Since the recent release of Material Design 3, the Angular Material is diligently trying to switch to it.
The problem is that I want to stay on Material Design 2, since most of the buttons have changed (for worse, IMHO), but there is no way for me to tell which are the latest version of the @angular/material and @angular/cdk packages that are running on Material Design 2.
Or is it some sort of a configuration that I have missed in my project?
I tried looking up the official documentation, but the link there to Material Design 2 is ... broken...
I also asked some AI bots, their response was: In summary, by checking the version of the Angular Material package you are using, you can infer which version of the Material Design specification your project is following. Versions 6.x and above are aligned with Material Design 2. But this is not really a solution (to deduct), I want to know for certain.

Which version of the material package are you relying on ?

@MatthieuRiegler it was @angular/material 17.3.10.

Angular Material before version 18 is using Material Design 2.
From version 18 and forward they are using Material Design 3.

M3 is accessible as experimental preview in 17.3
